# how to download multiple file simultaneously and join them in python?

Tags: python, download

I have some split files on a remote server.

I have tried downloading them one by one and join them. But it takes a lot of time. I googled and found that simultaneous download might speed up things. The script is on Python.

My pseudo is like this:

```
url1 = something
url2 = something
url3 = something

data1 = download(url1)
data2 = download(url2)
data3 = download(url3)

wait for all download to complete
join all data and save
```

Could anyone point me to a direction by which I can load files all simultaneously and wait till they are done.

I have tried by creating a class. But again I can't figure out how to wait till all complete.

I am more interested in Threading and Queue feature and I can import them in my platform.

I have tried with Thread and Queue with an example found on this site. Here is the code pastebin.com/KkiMLTqR . But it does not wait or waits forever..not sure

Comment: How could I do this with Threading/Queue?

Comment: You can create a thread pool yourself out of a `list` of `threading.Thread` objects and a `queue.Queue` object. But you don't really need to; `concurrent.futures` already wraps that up neatly. And, if you want to learn how to do it yourself, [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py) to its `ThreadPoolExecutor` is pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks. But I did not want to install backport/futures. I don't have that function available. And the final user won't have that too..

Comment: Why don't you have the ability to install a module off PyPI—especially one that's pure Python, no building C extensions necessary? And why can't you either package it with your program (if you're planning to distribute a Windows installer or something) or make it a prerequisite (if you're planning to distribute a script)? And, even if that really _is_ the case, why can't you just copy the files out of `futures` and put them into your project?

Comment: I'll give it a try. I am working on XBMC addons which doesn't have so many functions available.

Comment: I have tried with Thread and Queue with an example found on this site. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/KkiMLTqR . But it does not wait or waits forever..not sure

Comment: There are three big problems with your code. First, `run` returns a value, but nobody ever checks for that value. The normal way to do this is to use something mutable to stick the value in—another queue, or some other synchronized data structure if you need to preserve ordering, or by calling a setter method on the task itself, or by using a future, etc. Second, `run` only gets one URL off the queue, processes it, and quits, instead of looping until done. Third, relatedly, you have no way to drain the queue and exit once you're out of URLs. My answer and the linked stdlib code show solutions.

Comment: Meanwhile, [XBMC add-ons can, and often do, include third-party modules](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on_development#.2Fresources.2Flib.2F). But, even if they didn't, I already explained that the copy in `futures` is pure Python and can be just copied and pasted into your code; how could XBMC possibly cause a problem for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do things simultaneously. Or, really, 2-3/4 or so:

- Multiple threads

  - Or multiple processes, especially if the "things" take a lot of CPU power
  - Or coroutines or greenlets, especially if there are thousands of "things"
  - Or pools of one of the above
- Event loops (either coded manually)

  - Or hybrid greenlet/event loop systems like `gevent`.

---

If you have 1000 URLs, you probably don't want to do 1000 requests at the same time. For example, web browsers typically only do something like 8 requests at a time. A pool is a nice way to do only 8 things at a time, so let's do that.

And, since you're only doing 8 things at a time, and those things are primarily I/O bound, threads are perfect.

---

I'll implement it with [`futures`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html). (If you're using Python 2.x, or 3.0-3.1, you will need to install the backport, [`futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures).)

```
import concurrent.futures

urls = ['http://example.com/foo', 
        'http://example.com/bar']

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    result = b''.join(executor.map(download, urls))

with open('output_file', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

---

Of course you need to write the `download` function, but that's exactly the same function you'd write if you were doing these one at a time.

For example, using [`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html) (if you're using Python 2.x, use `urllib2` instead of `urllib.request`):

```
def download(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
        return f.read()
```

---

If you want to learn how to build a thread pool executor yourself, [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py) is actually pretty simple, and [`multiprocessing.pool`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py) is another nice example in the stdlib.

However, both of those have a lot of excess code (handling weak references to improve memory usage, shutting down cleanly, offering different ways of waiting on the results, propagating exceptions properly, etc.) that may get in your way.

If you look around PyPI and ActiveState, you will find simpler designs like [`threadpool`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/threadpool) that you may find easier to understand.

But here's the simplest joinable threadpool:

```
class ThreadPool(object):
    def __init__(self, max_workers):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.workers = [threading.Thread(target=self._worker) for _ in range(max_workers)]
    def start(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.start()
    def stop(self):
        for _ in range(self.workers):
            self.queue.put(None)
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()
    def submit(self, job):
        self.queue.put(job)
    def _worker(self):
        while True:
            job = self.queue.get()
            if job is None:
                break
            job()
```

Of course the downside of a dead-simple implementation is that it's not as friendly to use as `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
urls = ['http://example.com/foo', 
        'http://example.com/bar']
results = [list() for _ in urls]
results_lock = threading.Lock()

def download(url, i):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
        result = f.read()
    with results_lock:
        results[i] = url

pool = ThreadPool(max_workers=8)
pool.start()
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    pool.submit(functools.partial(download, url, i))
pool.stop()

result = b''.join(results)

with open('output_file', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async framwork like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com).

Alternatively this is one thing that Python's threads do ok at. Since you are mostly IO bound